# Issue creating function with a "with"

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, function

I am trying to create this function(variable names changed so allow naming mistakes as when tested original without function works fine),

```
 CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetQuality](@FruitID VARCHAR(200))
RETURNS varchar(200)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @Result varchar(200)

SET @Result = (

WITH 
latest AS
(
    SELECT * FROM (SELECT TOP 1 * FROM Fruits_Crate WHERE FruitID like @FruitID ORDER BY ExpiryDate DESC) a
), 
result AS
(
    SELECT 
        latest.ExpiryDate as LatestExpiryDate, latest.Size as LatestSize, latest.Weight as LatestWeight,
        previous.ExpiryDate as PreviousExpiryDate, previous.Size as PreviousSize, previous.Weight as PreviousWeight,
        CASE SIGN((latest.Weight * latest.Size) - (previous.Weight * previous.Size))
            WHEN 1 THEN 'Increased'
            WHEN 0 THEN 'Static'
            WHEN -1 THEN 'Decreased'
            ELSE 'No Previous Data'
        END AS Movement 
    FROM (SELECT TOP 1 * FROM (SELECT TOP 2 * FROM Fruits_Crate WHERE FruitID like @FruitID ORDER BY ExpiryDate DESC) x  ORDER BY ExpiryDate) previous
    FULL OUTER JOIN latest ON previous.FruitID = latest.FruitID
)

SELECT result.Movement AS FruitMovement from result;
)

RETURN @Result

END
```

**Error**

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure GetQuality, Line 10
> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WITH'.
>
> Msg 319, Level 15, State 1, Procedure GetQuality, Line 10
> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a common table expression, an xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking context clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon.
>
> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure GetQuality, Line 14
> Incorrect syntax near ','. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure GetQuality, Line 31 Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can move the assignment down, and put a semi colon before the with, and all should be good.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetQuality](@FruitID VARCHAR(200))
RETURNS varchar(200)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @Result varchar(200);

WITH 
latest AS
(
    SELECT * FROM (SELECT TOP 1 * FROM Fruits_Crate WHERE FruitID like @FruitID ORDER BY ExpiryDate DESC) a
), 
result AS
(
    SELECT 
        latest.ExpiryDate as LatestExpiryDate, latest.Size as LatestSize, latest.Weight as LatestWeight,
        previous.ExpiryDate as PreviousExpiryDate, previous.Size as PreviousSize, previous.Weight as PreviousWeight,
        CASE SIGN((latest.Weight * latest.Size) - (previous.Weight * previous.Size))
            WHEN 1 THEN 'Increased'
            WHEN 0 THEN 'Static'
            WHEN -1 THEN 'Decreased'
            ELSE 'No Previous Data'
        END AS Movement 
    FROM (SELECT TOP 1 * FROM (SELECT TOP 2 * FROM Fruits_Crate WHERE FruitID like @FruitID ORDER BY ExpiryDate DESC) x  ORDER BY ExpiryDate) previous
    FULL OUTER JOIN latest ON previous.FruitID = latest.FruitID
)

SELECT @RESULT = result.Movement AS FruitMovement from result;


RETURN @Result

END
```